# What's the meaning of this notation?

Tags: apoptosis

In [Wang et al.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2211124714002472), the authors state on page 663 at the top that

> Furthermore, **Bax<sup>-/-</sup> Bak<sup>-/-</sup>** cells were completely
>   resistant to paclitaxel-induced apoptosis.

What's the meaning of the `-/-` notation? Bax and Bak are proteins involved in apoptosis.

Answer (score 8):

-/- means both copies of the gene (both alleles) are knocked out

Comment: I guess I need to brush up on my molecular biology, but by "both copies" you mean, both copies present during mitosis?

Comment: As chromosomes come in pairs (bar the X chromosome in males), each gene is also present twice. -/- means both are knocked out.